# Accessing user disk storage in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, filesystems, manifest.json

I am building a chrome extension, I want to read and write in the user's disk storage. I want to make folders in users' documents, store screenshots, and delete and read. Is it possible?
I have searched, but could not find a way to do this, I want to know if it is possible, if it is possible, could you tell me, how to do that, or refer to some docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions cannot access the file system directly.
(except in very limited ways)

Native Messaging allows extensions to access the file system, by passing messages to and receiving messages from a native application, such as a Python script.
The native application (which you have to program yourself) then accesses the file system directly.

Because your question isn't specific, I can only refer you to the official documentation:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/